# gnus-posting styles no header in more specific case

Tags: email, emacs, gnus

I would like to add specific custom header in more general match (e.g. "^comp.") and add no such custom header in more specific match (e.g. "^comp.mail."). How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a good case for [Gnus Posting Styles](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Posting-Styles.html).

```
(
  ("^comp."
    ("X-Custom-Header" "Custom Stuff"))
  ("^comp.more.specific"
    ("X-Custom-Header" nil)))
```

If the value is `nil` the header will be removed. See one of the paragraphs in the huge wall of text that I linked above.